# Silverlight - Binding

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have information from different tables to bind on a Pop-up in a silverlight project.
My problem is that I can't bind those information because they are not in the same table.

how to bind the data contained in different tables in datagrid in silverlight appiliaction project.

Thank you

Comment: Create a new C# class, add necessary properties from different tables, and bind datagrid to this new class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EntityFramework, and the data from different tables are related, you might be able to use the dotted notation to perform the binding. e.g.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Address.City}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Invoice.TotalAmount}" />
```

If the information is on separate objects, you can manually set the datacontext on each item separately. e.g.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CustomerNameTextBlock" Text="{Binding CustomerName}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="CityTextBlock"         Text="{Binding City}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="TotalAmountTextBlock"  Text="{Binding TotalAmount}" /> 

this.CustomerNameTextBlock.DataContext = myCustomer;
this.CityTextBlock.DataContext         = myAddress;
this.TotalAmountTextBlock.DataContext  = myOrder;
```